# Viewing Code/Finding Error in SimBiology

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run a simulation of a chemical reaction in SimBiology, but when I run it I get the following error:

Error Details
Source: Time
Source Type: Plot Type
Source Location: Plot Types Library
Messages: Line 259: UIJ_AreThereWindowShowsPending - timeout waiting for window to show up

However, when I double-click on the error to view the code, the code it displays (the code for the 'Time' plot type) only shows 99 lines of code, in spite of the error supposedly being on line 259, and does not have any of the text of the error anywhere in it. How do I figure out where the actual error is occurring? Is there a main body of code that I haven't figured out how to access? If so, how do I view it?

This may be something painfully obvious I'm missing--I have very little experience with SimBiology. I did not write any of the reaction model using SimBiology--the reaction is written by an entirely different program and imported into SimBiology in SBML format (Level 2, Version 1 if it makes any difference).

Verifying the model produces no errors.

In Googling the text of the error itself, I've found a few different references to getting this error using MATLAB (though none specifically for SimBiology). I have tried inputting "close all" and "close all hidden" commands into MATLAB before running the simulation, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that something is going wrong with a lower level command to create the plot, such as `figure`. The line number will be from the lower level command rather than the Time plot type, which is why the line numbers don't match up.

Perhaps you could:

1. See whether any plots can be created at all from MATLAB
2. Disable the plots created after the task runs (uncheck them from the plot tab in the task pane), then run the task, export the data to MATLAB and create the plots from there
3. Copy and paste the code from the plot type library into an m-file, and run it from MATLAB.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I've since discovered that this is a bit weirder than I thought--MATLAB generates a simulation correctly if I go through the exact same process I was using on a computer running MATLAB. The version of MATLAB I was running was running off of a server I was sshing into, and that one still gives the error. I suppose it may just be a problem with the installation on the server, or that something is timing out somehow on it.